# Converting DynamoDB response to JSON

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

Below is my query to dynamoDB

```
var parse = AWS.DynamoDB.Converter.output;

b.query(params, function(err, results)  {
    if (err) {
        console.error("Unable to query. Error:", JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
        //callback(err);
    } else {
        console.log("Query succeeded.");
        console.log(JSON.stringify(results.Items));
        callback(null, results.Items);
        results.Items.forEach(function(element, index, array) {
        console.log( parse({"M": element.data.M }));
    });
    }
});
```

I have response "results.Items" from my DynamoDB like this

```
[{"id":{"S":"arena-MXHGMYzBBP5F6jztnLUdCL"},"data":{"M":{"phaseAngle":{"L":[{"N":"5.0753"},{"N":"5.0506"},{"N":"5.0267"},{"N":"5.0027"},{"N":"4.9793"},{"N":"4.9558"},{"N":"4.9319"},{"N":"4.9077"},{"N":"4.8835"},{"N":"4.8593"}]},"unitID":{"S":"arena-MXHGMYzBBP5F6jztnLUdCL"},"type":{"S":"DATA"},"version":{"S":"1.0.0"},"timestamp":{"N":"1582920097000"},"frequency":{"L":[{"N":"59.9596"},{"N":"59.9635"},{"N":"59.9619"},{"N":"59.9632"},{"N":"59.9616"},{"N":"59.9621"},{"N":"59.9619"},{"N":"59.9613"},{"N":"59.9613"},{"N":"59.9608"}]},"voltage":{"L":[{"N":"122.5669"},{"N":"122.5473"},{"N":"122.5593"},{"N":"122.5627"},{"N":"122.5382"},{"N":"122.5328"},{"N":"122.5758"},{"N":"122.5376"},{"N":"122.526"},{"N":"122.5364"}]}}},"timestamp":{"S":"1582920097000"}}]
```

I want to convert this to normal JSON, something which looks like this https://jxr5e29we5.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/prod/alldata

I used AWS.DynamoDB.Converter.output; and parse({"M": element.data.M }) gave the perfect json, but i am unable to return that output. Any help suggestions ? Thanks

Comment: "but i am unable to return that output." why? It sounds like you already found a solution, but gave up due to some other issue?

Comment: @MarkB hey i mean i was able to return that output but ```AWS.DynamoDB.Converter.output;``` this is not doing the right thing for me. After more search i found ```('dynamodb-marshaler').unmarshalItem``` this did the trick for me in converting. //BR

Comment: Will this work for you? https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/introducing-the-amazon-dynamodb-datamapper-for-javascript-developer-preview/. The unmarshaling should be handled by the library itself for you.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:
Import this
`var unmarshalItem = require('dynamodb-marshaler').unmarshalItem;`
I have the response here in "results.Items" and now you can do this to get the normal json format perfectly.

```
var items = results.Items.map(unmarshalItem);
        console.log(items);
        callback(null, items);
```

But i see this npm package was deprecated, So i will try doing this with latest `DynamoDB/Converter` and will update here.